# Django: How to update specific fields in extended model of User?

Tags: python, django

I'm relatively new to Django and am stuck on this. I've been trying to create a website where users can create their accounts, view their and other member's profile pages.

models.py

```
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    """docstring for ClassName"""
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    status = models.TextField(blank = True)
    desc = models.TextField(blank = True)
    portfolio_site = models.URLField(blank = True)
    profilepic = models.ImageField(blank = True, null = True, upload_to = 'profile_pics') 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget =  forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = UserProfileInfo
        fields = ('desc', 'portfolio_site', 'status', 'profilepic')
```

So, I want the user to be able to update their status from their homepage by typing into a text box.

index.html (the homepage from where the user can update their status)

```html
   

 <form method="POST" action="{% url 'app5:user_status' user.username %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputlg"></label>
          <input class="form-control input-lg" id="inputlg" type="text" name='status' placeholder="How are you feeling?">
        </div><center>
        <input type="submit" name='submitbtn' value='Add Status'>
        </center>
    </form>
```

Here's what my function to update the status in views.py looks like:

```
def user_status(request, username):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        mystatus = request.POST.get('status')
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        user.userprofileinfo.status = mystatus
        user.save()
        return redirect('app5:profilepage', username=username)
```

However, it does not work. If I try to update some other field like the username or email which is in the User Model instead of the UserProfileInfo extended model, `user.email = mystatus` works in that case. But the update doesn't take place when I try to update the status field of UserProfileInfo model. I'm pretty sure the error exists in the line: `user.userprofileinfo.status= mystatus`. I've searched in the documentation and many other sources but have been unable to find an answer.. How do I go about this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: I do not get any error when I click on Submit. It's just that the updation doesn't take place in the model and the status field stays the same as before.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I do not get any error. It's just that the change doesn't take place in the admin or the user profile page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You saved the user, not the userprofileinfo object. It's a separate model, so needs to be saved separately.

```
profile = user.userprofileinfo
profile.status = mystatus
profile.save()
```

Comment: Oh, I should have noted that. Thank you so much! That worked.

Answer (score 2):

if you have update field in UserProfileInfo then get the object for UserProfileInfo and update the field as below

```
def user_status(request,username):

    if request.method == 'POST':
         mystatus = request.POST.get('status')
         user = User.objects.get(username=username)
         userprofileinfo = user.userprofileinfo
         userprofileinfo.status = mystatus
         userprofileinfo.save()
         return redirect('app5:profilepage',username=username)
```